# Get VLC Media Runtime Data in C#

Tags: c#, video, media, vlc, audio-player

Im working on an Application which gets the Media Data(Length,time,frame/.etc) + Metadata from a running VLC Media Player Application, but i dont know how to get them,

I already tried getting Strings/Values through reading the process memory, but cant find anything, also i couldnt find any library in c#, which does this.

Comment: Is there a specific need to do this for a running 3rd party application, if would likely be easier to get all this information and more if you just created the player your self using one of many millions of apis

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.